# Excel convert range of dates into time to find whether it is greater or less than timeframe

Tags: excel-formula

I have the below formula doing a count of what rows have a time greater than 3:00pm OR a time less than 4:00am. It works as expected if my rows `E1:E5` are only times. However the issue is that column E is a date time and I would like to keep it that way. So the formula currently is returning `0`.

**Formula**

```
=COUNTIF(E1:E5,">="&TIME(15,0,0)) + COUNTIF(E1:E5,"<="&TIME(4,0,0))
```

**Column E**
10/1/2018 2:40:58 AM
10/1/2018 2:11:58 AM
10/1/2018 2:09:50 AM
10/1/2018 9:41:53 AM
10/1/2018 9:22:21 AM

The formula should return the count of 3. Thanks for any help.!

Comment: Date/Time values are actually just a decimal number in Excel. Anything left of the decimal is used as the date, anything right of the decimal is used for the time. So `12:00:00 PM` is actually `0.50` in decimal form, but `11/8/18 12:00:00 PM` is actually `43412.50`. So just a time value will never be greater than a date/time value. What this means is that you will first need to strip the date before comparing it to a time.

Comment: That makes sense. But how do you go about stripping the date from the range inside of a COUNTIF?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this - some methods are easier than others. Probably the easiest way would be to make a helper column (which could be hidden) that contains just the time of column E. Are you okay with a helper column?

Comment: You could use the `Mod()` or `Time()` ws functions. `Mod($E1, 1)` or `Time(Hour($E1), Minute($E1), Second($E1))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a helper column (which you can hide all the way in the `AA` column if you desire), you could do something like this:

If you decided to go with column `AA`, then in `AA1`, type:

```
=MOD($E1, 1)
```

and fill down. Any real number can be divided by itself, so **MOD** will just return the remainder - which would be the fractional number that represents the time.

Your `COUNTIF()` formula will then look like:

```
=COUNTIF($AA1:$AA5,">="&TIME(15,0,0)) + COUNTIF($AA1:$AA5,"<="&TIME(4,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by some of the suggestions I came up with the following:

[image]

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 ((A2:A17-TRUNC(A2:A17))>=0.625)*
 ((A2:A17-TRUNC(A2:A17))<=1))
 +SUMPRODUCT(
 ((A2:A17-TRUNC(A2:A17))>=0)*
 ((A2:A17-TRUNC(A2:A17))<=(1/6)))
```

Edit: As per the other answer, it's easier to read with `MOD` instead of `TRUNC`:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 (MOD(A2:A17,1)>=0.625)*
 (MOD(A2:A17,1)<=1))
 +SUMPRODUCT(
 (MOD(A2:A17,1)>=0)*
 (MOD(A2:A17,1)<=(1/6)))
```

Explanation:

`A2:A17-TRUNC(A2:A17)` returns only the decimal part of the number - time

`0.625` - 15:00 (3 pm)

`1` - midnight

`0` - midnight

`=0.166667` or `1/6` - 4:00 (4 am)

I'm sure there are other ways of doing it but this one seems pretty simple and does not require a helper column.